# Why did this post turn up in the first post review queue?

Tags: bug, review-queues, first-posts

I was happily wasting my time here when I stumbled upon [this post in the first post review queue](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/29674):

[image]

In case it’s not clear enough the damn thing seems to be a month old. It wasn’t there when I was in the review queue earlier. (I link visiting queues. They give nice and shiny badges =D.)

I reviewed as I deemed necessary ([no-action-needed](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/no-action-needed)) but I can’t help asking myself: What happened here?

Comment: I've also seen sth like that lately.

Comment: [status-completed]

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. [votes-lacking] ;)

Comment: Actually, the better choice is [tag:status-bydesign] xD

Comment: [you-little-was-that-all-for-hats]

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. [Nope-legitimate-issue-but-hats!]

Answer (score 5):

This has happened to me too. The closest I found on mother meta is this post: [Old first post reviews on sites without audits enabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235024/old-first-post-reviews-on-sites-without-audits-enabled) There's something similar on meta.SO: [Old first posts in first posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273176/old-first-posts-in-first-posts-queue)

So Shog's answer basically says that when either

- a user's first post gets deleted
- a user's reputation is dramatically affected due to bounties, spam flags etc.

their older posts comes to count as a new first post, while it's usually not the case and you see first posts as literally new posts from new users.

I have a hunch in this case the user's **other post** got deleted, hence the question in the review in question matched the criteria for appearing as a first post.

<s>A mod can prove me right or wrong tho'. The user has three badges, all of which were awarded for the only undeleted post they have. Another possibility could be that they undeleted the post and that caused this hullabaloo, but that's unlikely since the deletion and undeletion happened on the same day they asked the question.</s> OK, per [@Mart's comment](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3040/why-did-this-post-turn-up-in-the-first-post-review-queue/3042?noredirect=1#comment2530_3042), this *was* the case. Happy Ending

Comment: Anyone with access to the 10k tools should be able to confirm that; there’s a tab *recently deleted* where it should show up. Unfortunately, neither of us have 10k (yet) ^^'

Comment: Yeah sure. Now someone go confirm before $\ldots$

Comment: Before what? And there are a few, read many, deleted questions of that user.  Is that the confirmation you were looking for?

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Yeah, possibly. What numbers are we talking about? Five? Twenty? If that was the problem, we can probably find that user’s actual first question in that deletion list and find out it was deleted around a day ago …

Comment: @Mart the confirmation would be that round the time of that review another post of the same user got deleted.

Comment: Yes there was a post of that user automagically removed about 15 minutes earlier.

Comment: (づ｡◕‿‿◕｡)づ @Martin. Case closed.